# Oracle performance on a table

Tags: performance, oracle, query-optimization

I have table with 100 million rows.  I have to use BETWEEN operator and query is very slow.  Have to get all rows that are either in range for amount and price or all with that city and state.

I have 2 indexes one on t.name and another on t.city & t.state.

Performance of this query is very slow.  How can I improve this query.

```
SELECT t.trader_id, t.name, t.city, t.state 
  FROM trader t 
  WHERE t.name = 'john test' AND
        is_valid = 1 AND
        ((t.amount BETWEEN (-2500.0000 , 2800.000) AND
          t.price between (25.00000 , 58.000000)) OR 
        (t.city='city' AND
         t.state='state'))
```

The has non-unique Indexes present on

1. t.name
2. t.city, t.state

For (name and is_valid) there are about 78000 rows.  For (price and amount) there are about 331809 rows. For (city and state) there are about 13500 rows.

Comment: Is the table partitioned? Indexed? what's the execution plan of the query? Is dynamic sampling being invoked (the execution plan tells you). How many of the rows meet the first two criteria?

Comment: table is indexed.  Have 2 indexes one on t.name and another on t.city&t.state.  Upon performing execution plan, it shows that for amount, price , city & state INDEX BY ROWID is performed.  while for name t.name index is used.  Problem is from t.price, t.amount, t.city and t.state.

Comment: David, this is not duplicate this query is looking at only 1 table not multiple tables.

Comment: Please edit your question and correct the syntax errors.  It's unlikely your question will be taken seriously if you post code that can't be compiled.  Thanks.

Comment: Out of the total 100M rows in the table, how many rows the query actually returns? Also, could you show us the exact table DDL, query plan and execution time?

Comment: We also need to know which columns are indexed, and the data distributions.  How many rows match that combination of (name, is_valid)?  How many rows match that combination of (city, state)?How many rows match that combination of (amount, price)?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided much hard information such as explain plans, presence of indexes or data distribution.  Which reduces any answer to a guess.

However, your question is probably titled wrongly.  The BETWEEN operator is unlikely to be the main cause of the poor performance.  You have an OR clause which specifies two completely different sets of criteria.  So the database can't use any index on AMOUNT, PRICE, CITY or STATE.  That throws the burden onto the remaining criteria.  Unless you have a compound index on (NAME, IS_VALID) *and* that combination returns a very small percent of rows you're looking at a full table scan.  A full table scan of 100 million rows will take some time to execute.

What you can do about it really depends on the details I specified in my opening sentence.  Guessing at solutions on top of a guessed diagnosis is just a waste of everybody's time.  Provide some details and then we can discuss it further.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.  Below is the information on the query.
Non-partioned, Non-unique Index is present on 1) t.name 2) t.city and t.state
By name and is_valid, there are about 78000 rows
price and amount there are about 331809 rows.  Full table SCAN is being done for this criteria.
city and state, there are about 13500 rows.

Comment: Comments should be disposable.  Please *edit your question* when posting additional information.  Apart from anything else the formatting sucks.  Who can understand the explain plan like that?.

Comment: OPERATION        OBJECT_NAME   OPTIONS        COST      

SELECT STATEMENT     

  TABLE ACCESS TRADER BY INDEX ROWID 21  
       Filter Predicates  
    AND  
          t.valid_listing =1  
              OR  
    AND  
     t.price > = 10.00  
     t.amount <= 40000.00  
     t.amount >= 100000.00  
     t.price <= 1.00   
     NVL(t.price,1) <> 1  
     NVL(t.amount, 2) <> 2  
    AND  
                       t.city='baltimore'  
     t.state = 'MD'  

INDEX TRADER_NAME RANGE SCAN  4  
   Access Predicates  
  T.NAME='trader1'

Comment: I tried EDITING and set as CODE format Ctrl-K .. but I am unable to format .. what should I do to format as CODE ..